# Java Hibernate javax.persistence.Transient Annotation on Reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reflection

I have a simple class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
   private String fullName;
   javax.persistence.Transient
   private String getFullNameWithPoint(){return this.name+" "+fullName+".";}
}
```

I iterate all over the fields but i need to know which fields has the **javax.persistence.Transient annotation** how can i do this?

I have something like this

```
if(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()) && !java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers()) && !java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && !Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) && !Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
```

With this condition i know which field has the transient annotation but the java transient

```
!java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers())
```

But i need to know which fields are market with javax.persistence.Transient Annotation is possible?

Thanks a lot a best regards sorry by my poor english

I cannot modify the signature of the property mean i cannot do this

```
private transient String fullName;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [getAnnoataion()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29) it returns `null` if this field doesn't contain this annotation

```
if(field.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Transient.class) != null){
//enters here if the field has this annotation
}
```